# Node JS , Express : upload file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, gridfs

I want to send a file:

```
// Upload a file from loca file-system to MongoDB
app.post('/api/file/upload', (req, res) => {

    var filename = req.query.filename;
    //  here ..... request please 

    console.log(file + " and" + tempPath );

    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename });
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/uploads/" + filename).pipe(writestream);
    writestream.on('close', (file) => {
        res.send('Stored File: ' + file.filename);
    });
});
```

I want to send a file to mongoose (Gridfs), in this API test with Postman

Comment: And what keeps you from doing it? Is there any error given when you execute the given code?

Answer (score 0):

How about using https://www.npmjs.org/package/gridfs-stream

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var GridFS = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);


app.post('/api/file/upload', (req, res) => {

    var writestream = GridFS.createWriteStream({
        filename: req.query.filename
    });

    writestream.on('close', function (file) {
      callback(null, file);
    });

    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(writestream);
});
```

Note that path is the path of the file on the local system.